# CUDA - copy to array within array of Objects

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I have a CUDA application I'm working on with an array of Objects; each object has a pointer to an array of `std::pair<int, double>`.  I'm trying to cudaMemcpy the array of objects over, then cudaMemcpy the array of pairs to each of the objects, however this is giving me all kinds of grief.  It crashes attempting to copy to the inner array; I don't understand how to move this over...

```
#include <cuda.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
public:
    int id;
    float something;
    std::pair<int, float> *somePairs;
};

Object *objects;

void initObjects()
{
    objects = new Object[10];

    for( int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++ )
    {
        objects[idx].id = idx;
        objects[idx].something = (float) idx;
    objects[idx].somePairs = new std::pair<int, float>[10];

        for ( int jdx = 10; jdx < 10; jdx++ )
        {
           objects[idx].somePairs[jdx] = std::pair<int, float>( jdx, (float) jdx );
        }

    }
}



void cudaMemcpyObjects()
{
     Object *devObjects;

     cudaMalloc( &devObjects, sizeof(Object) * 10 );
     cudaMemcpy( devObjects, objects, sizeof(Object) * 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

     for ( int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++ )
     {
         size_t pairSetSize = sizeof(std::pair<int, float>) * 10;

         // CRASH HERE ... v
         cudaMalloc( &(devObjects[idx].somePairs), pairSetSize );
         cudaMemcpy( devObjects[idx].somePairs, objects[idx].somePairs,
                     sizeof( std::pair<int, float> ) * 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

     }


}


int main()
{
    initObjects();
    cudaMemcpyObjects();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It begs the question: Why? C++ standard library container classes aren't supported in CUDA code.

Comment: Well, for one, you can read STD containers in CUDA code.  You can reference .first and .second easily.  Though you can substitute this for any array-within-array and the same problem arises.

Comment: The CUDA standard library does not contain definitions for any c++ containers, and host versions won't compile without considerable modification. I would very much like to see a self contained repro kernel demonstrating this, if you care to post one.

Comment: @talonmies - this:  http://pastebin.com/62L0a13J  - A particularly useless example, but compiles and runs.  Again, my counter to your comment was that one _could_ read std containers in CUDA.  You cannot call host code from CUDA, so things like vector.at(i) or the like will not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My CUDA experience is only in its infancy, but I believe the error is like this:

`cudaMalloc` is a *host* function that wants to write the pointer into *host* memory. However, you are passing to it a pointer in *device* memory!

To fix this, you should first create the device pointers and fill them into your host object structure, and only then copy the whole thing over to the device, and also copy the individual pairs over to the device as well.

Schematically:

```
struct Bar;

struct Foo
{
  int tag;
  Bar * bp;
};

void setup()
{
  Foo * hFoo = new Foo[10];

  Foo * dFoo;
  cudaMalloc(dFoo, sizeof(Foo) * 10);

  for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
  {
    Bar * dBar;
    cudaMalloc(&dbar, sizeof(Bar));

    Bar b;  // automatic temporary -- we never keep a host copy of this
    cudaMemcpy(dBar, &b, sizeof(Bar));

    hFoo[i].bp = dBar;    // this is already a device pointer!
  }

  cudaMemcpy(dFoo, hFoo, sizeof(Foo) * 10);
}
```

On the return, don't forget that the `Foo::bp` are *device* pointers that you still need to copy back one by one!

It would probably be easier to just have one self-contained class that you can move in one go, but that may not be practical, or desirable for reasons of memory locality. You have to thing carefully about this. If the member is just a pair, why not put the two items in the main class directly?

Comment: cudaMalloc does take a device pointer. Are you confused with cudaMallocHost?

Comment: I wasn't expecting this to be nearly so painful.  I was hoping there was just something obvious that I was missing.  (The actual constructs in my code are much more than just a struct with a pair, this was simply an example to show the problem.)  Kerrek, your solution might work if I keep two pointers per object, one for host and one for dev...

Comment: Come to think of it, why didn't I think of that before...?

class foo
{
    // some variables
    float *data;
    float *deviceData;
};

Comment: Something like that... you'll have to create everything on the host, one way or another, and then get everything onto the device, and then back. Any manual allocation will have to be aware of this. Alternatively, you could try mapped memory  though, that might be easier (that's where your `cudaMallocHost` comes in).

Comment: @trycatch: You'd needlessly be using up space for pointers that you don't need, though.

Comment: @Kerrek Ah, that's how you meant it. I misunderstood

Comment: I think using mapped memory and allocating all your dynamic storage on that (placement-new) might be a feasible idea, because you'll just have to create everything once.

Comment: @Kerrek:  needlessly?  How so?  I don't follow.  The *data pointer is for the actual data, the *deviceData is for moving it to the device so I can use it in my kernels.  It's quite a large lookup table, different sizes for different objects.  I do see the potential for mapped memory though I've never used it before at all and don't know how it handles arrays-in-arrays.

Comment: Kerrek SB's approach is the correct way to do this.  Assign the inner device pointer to the outer (host) struct's pointer member variable, then copy the whole initialized outer host struct to the outer device struct.  CUDA 4.0's UVA should make this simpler -- you can access the host memory directly and copy what you need to the device inside the kernel that uses it.

Comment: @trycatch: With mapped memory you don't have to copy anything. To make sure that you can dynamically allocate inside the mapped memory, you'll have to override your `new` operators though or use some sort of placement-new, or a custom allocator.